# Tiff IFilter not working for SQL 32 bit on Windows 64 bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, tiff, ifilter

I have the following environment

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit
- SQL Server 2005 32-bit

I am trying to load up the TIFF IFilter into SQL Server but it does not appear in the following sql command:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_document_types
```

I have installed TIFF IFilter via control panel and turned on Windows features and run the following in SQL:

```
sp_fulltext_service 'load_os_resources',1
sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature',0
```

then restarted SQL Server and also tried rebooting.

I believe the problem is that SQL Server is 32-bit and the Windows installation is 64-bit and so SQL server is perhaps looking in all the 32-bit directories and registries for any filters.

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the tifffilt.dll for 32-bit machines and register that (unless the 64-bit is built for any CPU) and then somehow put that where SQL Server 32-bit can find it.

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hi Andrew, thank you for replying. I have turned that off, I am fairly sure that is this line:

[code](sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature',0)

Comment: Please excuse the brackets it was my attempt to format it correctly, I failed!

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway.